# How do I add a custom tab to a Facebook application profile page programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to add custom tabs to my Facebook pages, by using the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API),
[https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/tabs] and using HTTP POST.

However, I am unable to add custom tabs to my Facebook application's profile page. Infact the API, [https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/tabs], with HTTP GET also fails.

(I mean, I cannot even get the tabs for my Facebook application's profile page with the API.)

What am I doing wrong?

Here I am listing what I am trying to do:

1. I get an `access_token` (say a1) for a user (admin_user) using the `manage_pages` permission.
2. With this access_token (a1), I use Graph API, >[https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts] and get back a list of pages (pages and application profile pages):

   {
     "data": [
       {
         "name": "Bg",
         "access_token": "*********",
         "category": "Industrials",
         "id": "***********"
       },
       {
         "name": "Testapp2Pip",
         "access_token": "***************",
         "category": "Application",
         "id": "*********"
       },
3. Now I use the Graph API, [https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/tabs]

Case 1. If I use the `page_id` for the background page (which is a normal page) and the corresponding access_token, I get back the tabs for the page.

Case 2. If I use the `page_id` for the Testapp2Pip page (which is an application profile page) and the corresponding access_token, I get an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request.",
        "type": "GraphMethodException"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the tabs for an application profile page? Also, I would actually want to add custom tabs to the application profile page by using Graph API.

Comment: for example . say i have an app with appid xyz. I also have the page access token for the app (got by https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts). Now when i want to get the tabs for the app profile page with[https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/tabs].. it gives error Unsupported get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is a bug. I have [filed the bug with Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/278629562166716?browse=search_4eb22ce37720b1837899919).

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the app to the app profile page, and/or double checked that it is added as an app? It seems odd, but you can add/remove the app from the apps own page. I'm guessing if the app isn't added, then it wouldn't have access to the page information.

An alternative option is to get an access token for the application, not the current user. This page has instructions for getting an access token for the app, instead of the user. Scroll down to the "App Login" section.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: i want to add a custom tab (application) to a page by using graph api. While i am able to do that to a normal page, i am unable to add a custom tab to an application profile page by using graph api.

Comment: You can just add a tab. You have to add an application that can be accessed via a tab. First you add the app to your page, then you indicate whether you want it shown as a tab or not. The app has to support/be configured to support pages.

Comment: Exactly that is what i am saying.. i am unable to add a app to a different app profile page by using graph api

Comment: That's because a user must grant permission to add an app to a page. Apps can't add themselves, even if the user is an admin of the page. An app can only prompt the user for permission to do something.

Comment: you are getting it all wrong .. i suspect :) I already have a access_token with manage_pages permission. I should be able to add custom tabs to a page by using this token and graph api. While i am able to add a custom tab to a normal page, i am not able to add custom tab to a **application profile page**.